# Angular form that contains nested directive not validating

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a very simplified bit of html like so:

```
<call-panel>
    <form name="hotListForm" >
        <twilio>
            <input type="text" name="phoneOtherText" id="phoneOtherText" class="form-control" required="required" ng-model="phoneNumber" ng-pattern="validation" ng-trim="false"/>
            <span class="error" ng-show="hotListForm.phoneOtherText.$error.pattern">Not a valid phone number</span>
        </twilio>
    </form>
</call-panel>
```

But this doesn't work. Is there a special way to do this when in a nested directive. I have verified pattern is available.

Screenshot of it definitely being in the form and of form structure:
[image]

Comment: You should delete this question because the title is misleading. It was a simple honest mistake. Nothing to do with nested directives. When people search they find this and there is nothing useful in it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not working probably because you have the id set to "phoneOtherText" as well, try changing the id and try

Comment: I tried renaming the id to just phoneOther and it didn't work. Then I tried to rename the 'name' to phoneOther and changing the id back to phoneOtherText still the same.

Comment: figured it out. $parent.hotListForm.phoneOtherText.$error.pattern fixed it